# backgroudworker report progress c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

My code:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler  (worker_ProgressChanged);
worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{

     ResourceConsumingFunction();
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
        Finished(true);
};
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I wish to report progress quite frequently but have no idea how to do this. I cant modify resourceConsumingFunction(); 
Any ideas?

Comment: Does resourceConsumingFynction throw any progress events? If so, catch the event and then inside call the backgroundWorker ReportProgress method. Then catch the bgw progress event and update GUI from there.

Comment: It could be a smell that your method is consuming a lot a resource. Maybe you can split `ResourceConsumingFunction()` into smaller methods and therefore be able to report progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen correctly points out - if you cant get info back from ResourceConsumingFunction about progress then you can't report it.
You need some way to hook into ResourceConsumingFunction to measure its progress.  Is it creating files, writing something to disk or altering accessable variables that you can measure/use as progress value without having access to the workings of the function?
If you can't get an external handle on the progress of this function then your doomed.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't modify `ResourceConsumingFunction` your out of luck.

Since `ResourceConsumingFunction` does all the work, if you can't modify it to report the progress back, how do you expect to be able to show progress? The rest of your code can't magically guess how long `ResourceConsumingFunction` is going to run for before it's complete.